# bash: find and grep with regex in shellscript

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have several versions of a certain software (lets call it *MySoftware*)installed and I like to find the path to a specific version with a combination of `find` and `grep`.
Assume I have the following versions:
1.12.0
1.12.2
1.42.2

It is stored in the following way:

```
~/src/MySoftware/1.12.0/...
~/src/MySoftware/1.12.2/...
~/src/MySoftware/1.42.2/...
```

In a shell I could do something like `find . -name MySoftware | grep 1.12.0`. This is working since the command is giving me the  `~/src/MySoftware/1.12.0/` path.

However, when switching to a shell script, I try to do this:

```
find . -name "MySoftware"  -exec grep "1\.12\.0" {} ';'
```

The example above is, however, not returning anything and I have no idea why. Other tries with `grep -HF "1.12.0"` are also not working. I am grateful for any advice

Comment: Your file `MySoftware` contains string `1.12.0`?

Comment: @Cyrus: yes, sorry that wasn't clear. I changed to text

Comment: Given the directory structure in the question, I fail to understand how the command `find . -name MySoftware | grep 1.12.0` gives `~/src/MySoftware/1.12.0/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note the difference!

In the first example, `find . -name MySoftware | grep 1.12.0` you are building a list with the names of the files and then you grep the specific version.

However, in the second example you are trying to find same files *AND* you are trying to grep in those files!!!

So, with this:

```
find . -name "MySoftware"  -exec grep "1\.12\.0" {} ';'
```

You are searching in those files!!!

I would suggest you to do this:

```
find . -type f -name "MySoftware" | grep 1.12.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is working. This solution is adding the term ```(standard input):``` in front of the result. Is there a way to NOT do that? I would like to use it in a variable for further processing

Comment: I think the output of find contains some non-ASCII characters... And 'grep' thinks that the input is a "binary" file...

Try this: find . -type f -name "MySoftware" 2>/dev/null | grep -aE '1.12.0'

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!